# Plotting two distributions on same plot

Tags: julia

I am trying to plot two probability distributions onto the same plot. One is a *uniform distribution* with area under the curve = 1 and the other is a *chi distribution* (or to be more specific, a Maxwellian) with three degrees of freedom with area under the curve = 1. Here is my code so far:

```
using Plots, Distributions
gr()

v = -0.5:0.001:1.5
f_s0 = pdf.(Uniform(0,1), v) # uniform distribution with area 1
F_s = pdf.(Chi(3), v)  # chi distribution with area 1

plot(v, f_s0, label="f_s0")
plot!(v, F_s, linecolor = :orange, linestyle = :dash, label="F_s (Maxwellian)")
xlabel!("velocity")
ylabel!("probability density")
xlims!(-0.5, 1.5)
ylims!(0, 1.5)
```

When I run this, I get

```
DomainError with -0.5:
log will only return a complex result if called with a complex argument. Try log(Complex(x)).
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chi distribution is only defined on the nonnegative numbers, and this is really a constraint of math rather than programming. If you are considering a Chi distribution, this may suggest that the quantity you are considering cannot even *be* negative, in which case the answer is to only plot for positive x values anyways. Nonetheless, if you want to show the Uniform distribution going back to zero, then I would do something like the following.

```
using Plots, Distributions

vᵤ = -0.1:0.005:4
f_s0 = pdf.(Uniform(0,1), vᵤ) # uniform distribution with area 1
plot(vᵤ, f_s0, label="f_s0", framestyle=:box)

vᵪ = 0:0.005:4
F_s = pdf.(Chi(3), vᵪ)  # chi distribution with area 1

plot!(vᵪ, F_s, linecolor = :orange, linestyle = :dash, label="F_s (Maxwellian)")
xlabel!("velocity")
ylabel!("probability density")
xlims!(-0.1, 4)
ylims!(0, 1.5)
```

yielding
[image: Uniform and Chi distributions]

Comment: Great, thanks! Two unrelated questions: (1) Are you still keeping the area under chi = 1, (2) How do I make the legend subscript labels work?

Comment: (1) yes, since it's a proper distribution (2) you could try unicode subscripts (try typing `\_s<tab>` in Julia, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Chi distribution starts from zero so this should be:

```
F_s = pdf.(Chi(3), 0:0.001:1.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a issue with `Distributions`, you can define a function as a workaround:

```
using Plots, Distributions
gr()

v = -0.5:0.001:1.5
f_s0 = pdf.(Uniform(0,1), v) # uniform distribution with area 1

CHIPDF(x) = x>0 ? pdf(Chi(3),x) : 0

F_s = CHIPDF.(v)  # chi distribution with area 1

plot(v, f_s0, label="f_s0")
plot!(v, F_s, linecolor = :orange, linestyle = :dash, label="F_s (Maxwellian)")
xlabel!("velocity")
ylabel!("probability density")
xlims!(-0.5, 1.5)
ylims!(0, 1.5)
```